# Writing to the external storage

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-external-storage

I'm trying to write to external storage from my Android app, specifically the downloads folder. I'm trying to write a text file.

I have got the write to external storage request in my manifest, and am asking explicitly for the permissions, and accepting.

However, my code is always catching an exception at the below line.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(destinationFile);
```

My current code for writing to the file, once permissions have been sought, is below.

```
File destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);
if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
    destinationFile.mkdirs();
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(destinationFile);
fw.write(plainStr);
fw.flush();
fw.close();


} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I'm using toasts to track progress through that code, and it never makes it past that line I mentioned earlier.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: please post your logcat what error it presents

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to Android dev, where can I get those?

Comment: on bottom stub of your android view there is a tab called Logcat just press that and watch the logcat there when your app crashes

Comment: Ok, so I've got a logcat. It's hundreds of lines long. Any pointers as to what I'm looking for?

Comment: just only use the filter for error! there should be some exception there

Comment: Not getting anything. I am pretty sure it's catching on the statement I've just added to op.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170559/discussion-between-rizwan-atta-and-boshjailey).

Comment: You can just place a Toast in that catch block and display e.getMessage().

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a file with that name as you used mkdirs() to create a directory with that name already.

Comment: I've removed the mkdirs if statement, no effect.

Comment: If that is all you did then that is not enough of course. You should delete that directory first. Or use a different name.